# Как вывести содержимое из файла *.txt на страницу?

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести содержимое из файла *.txt на страницу? Есть файл, в котором лежат переменные, одну из переменных нужно вывести на экран. Делаю так

```
<?php
$filetxt = get_file_content('путь к файлу');
//echo $filetxt; эта переменная на главной странице.
?>
```

`echo $filetxt;` - это помещается на главную страницу, естественно главная страница связана с той страницей, которую необходимо вывести - `include('echo.php');`
Но эффекта никакого, пустой экран...

Comment: Совет: Вам нужно изменить уровень вывода ошибок добавив в файл .htaccess, расположенный в корне сайта, следующую строчку:  
php_value error_reporting E_ALL  
Сделав это Вы поймете почему вызвав **get_file_content** Вы должны были увидеть Fatal error, а не пустой экран.

Comment: Вы не правильно задали вопрос.

Answer (score 6):

```
echo file_get_contents($filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот код чтения файла:

```
$filename = 'name.txt';
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
echo $contents;
```

Если вам просто вывести `php` скрипт и чтобы он исполнился, то инклюдить в нужном месте. Можно конечно и получить его фаилгетконтентс и через евал пустить, но это извращения.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Помогло!!!